# How to list existing directories from a CSV in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, pipe

I want to list directory names that exist from a CSV file so I tried this but it fails :

```
PS C:\Users\myHomeDIR> cat .\toto.csv
".\.config" , "C:\DAFI"
PS C:\Users\myHomeDIR> cat .\toto.csv | dir | % FullName
dir : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '".\.config" , "C' does not exist.
At line:1 char:18
+ cat .\toto.csv | dir | % FullName
+                  ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (".\.config" , "C:String) [Get-ChildItem], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS C:\Users\myHomeDIR>
```

I expect this output :

```
C:\Users\myHomeDIR\.config
dir : Cannot find path 'C:\DAFI' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:27
+ ".\.config" , "C:\DAFI" | dir | % FullName
+                           ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\DAFI:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

PS C:\Users\myHomeDIR>
```

Comment: Your `cat` command outputs a single string with verbatim quotes in it, not two string values. The equivalent on the command line would have been `'".\.config" , "C:\DAFI"' | dir | ...`, which understandably produces the error you see

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen OK, now how do I get `'".\.config" , "C:\DAFI"'` to become `".\.config" , "C:\DAFI"` ?

Comment: You could do `(cat filepath) -split ',' |ForEach-Object Trim '"' | dir | ...`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It fails with this `dir : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:57
+ (cat .\toto.csv) -split ',' | ForEach-Object Trim '"' | dir
+                                                         ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\Users\myHomeDIR\.config" :String) [Get-ChildItem], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

...`

Comment: Oh, because of the spaces, try with `-split '\s*,\s*'` instead. Alternatively use `Import-Csv` and then pass the resulting property values to `dir`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks. I guess it's better for me to have one dir per line instead of using a CSV file.

Comment: If you have a .csv file, why not use `Import-Csv`?